# Barcode CODE_128 using PrintHTML with Qz Tray

Tags: qz-tray

Good Day All,

Right now, i'm trying to print using HTML with Qz-Tray. Can i make a barcode on that template HTML. The Problem is, that HTML template is STRING so it can not be change it using Javascript and I'm Trying to use Libre Font 128 Font Family but still not working.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?font=Libre%20Barcode%20128 i  want to use that library, in this

```
function printHTML() {
    var config = getUpdatedConfig();

    var colA = '<h2>*&nbsp; QZ Print Plugin HTML Printing &nbsp;*</h2>' +
            '<span style="color: #F00;">Version:</span> ' + qzVersion + '<br/>' +
            '<span style="color: #F00;">Visit:</span> https://qz.io/';
    var colB = '<img src="' + getPath() + '/assets/img/image_sample.png">';

    var printData = [
        {
            type: 'html',
            format: 'plain',
            data: '<html>' +
            '   <table style="font-family: monospace; border: 1px;">' +
            '       <tr style="height: 6cm;">' +
            '           <td valign="top">' + colA + '</td>' +
            '           <td valign="top">' + colB + '</td>' +
            '       </tr>' +
            '   </table>' +
            '</html>'
        }
    ];

    qz.print(config, printData).catch(displayError);
}
```

or this https://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html

Comment: QZ Tray uses JavaFX for HTML and fonts can be tricky to get right, more info here: https://groups.google.com/g/qz-print/c/8WJKPrRlCYE/m/CwpZE-LCAwAJ.  In regards to HTML template string, that should be workable.  Can you please update the question with sample code to work from and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, i can figure it out. Thanks for the Link mate.